# Can changesets in mercurial repositories be merged chronologically?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to re-use code from project A in project B (both in separate repositories), so I'd like to move several files from the original project repository A to a common repository C which will be used by project B. (dependencies managed by Maven, etc.)

I can extract just the files I want to move from A into their own 'filtered' repository F using the convert extension and some additional scripts (to discover the complete history of said files).

At this stage I could:
a) pull F into C, merge and commit, or
b) export all of F changes as patches then import them into C
However both approaches lead to a repository C whose changesets are not chronologically ordered. I see the history of F prepended to the history of C.

Is it possible to 'merge' two repositories such that the changesets are ordered chronologically?

I have scripts to do this - but so far, I've had to completely rebuild C each time I move a different set F from A. (By exporting all C and F as patches, creating a new C, then importing all the patches in chronological order).

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need some examples of how you do this. You should not rebuild your repositories like that on a regular basis.

Comment: Exactly Lasse - it's a pain, which is why I'm looking for a better/proper solution. As for how I'm doing it, I export all the changesets from C anf F into a set of .patch files, use a perl script to determine the chronological ordering of these based on the datestamp in their header comments, then init a new C, and import all the patches in this order. Then I have to reset C at Google Code, and push the new C to Google.

Comment: Why is it important that they be chronological? If just for aesthetic purposes, I'd say just bite the bullet and take one of your straightforward approaches. If not, how can you be sure that chronological ordering gives the results you want, if F (as part of A) and C have evolved independently until now? Do you e.g. want to be able to check out C (with F) as of a particular time, and expect everything to be consistent? My gut reaction is that you'll need manual intervention even if blind chronological ordering does get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for the response shambulator. My wish to have the changesets chronologically ordered is so that I could see how my two merged sets of code looked at a particular point in time - as they would have looked at that time, had I developed them in the same repository. I've just tried merging two of these 'F' repositories into 'C', then updating C to a date where I know the state of two files in each F - resulting in one of the files being present, but not the other.

Comment: **"...had I developed them in the same repository."** But is this synthetically altered view of history important enough to go through this hassle? e.g. do you have to be able to check out the combined code as of a particular date in order to use it in another project, or are you just curious? :) I have found a (painful, possibly scriptable) way of merging F & C (to a 3rd branch) at chosen dates, then committing the merges with `--date` to impose the time order - but is it worth it? Could you not simply pull them into different branches, then merge and declare "combined history starts here"?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The parent of a changeset is built-into its nodeid (which is a cryptographic hash), so you can't reorder the actual parentage of changesets without completely altering/rebuilding them.

You can bring changesets into a repository in any order you want provided that the changeset's parent changeset precedes it.

So if A and B have the following changesets with the following revision numbers (r=) and creation times (t=):

```
A: null----[A r=0,t=0]----[C r=1,t=2]----[E r=2,t=4]
B: null----[B r=0,t=1]----[D r=1,t=3]----[F r=2,t=5]
```

You could, with careful pulling create a repository like this:

```
C: null----[A r=0,t=0]-------------------[C r=2,t=2]-------------------------[E r=4,t=4]
     \
      \-----------------[B r=1,t=1]--------------------[D r=3,t=3]------------------[F r=5,t=5]
```

There's, however little value in doing that as the sequence number of the changeset (r above) is meaningless).

Ideally your repository B would be a clone of A with all of its local modifications existing only in B.  That way if you fix a bug in A you can pull into B and then merge to get that fix.  Transplant/convert is a hollow substitute.  Another option is to have the common parts of A and B extracted out into repo C which both A and B would then use as a Mercurial subrepository.

Comment: Thank you for your response Ry4an. What I'm trying to achieve is your 'careful pulling' diagram, with the sequence numbering you show, but all on one branch, rather than merged. Just as though I'd developed the code in A and B in the same repository. Then I can go back to a particular time and see both sets of code as they were at that time (see response to shambulator) - with merging, I seem to be able to go back to a point in time on the top or bottom branch, but the changes that should be present on the 'other' branch are not visible.